# iOS - UI Automation multiple scripts with reset application

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I am looking for solution where I can set my javascripts with order and when each script would start it would be independent on previous scripts. So I can run just one script or group of them and it would be working same.

I find that I can create one script file and use `#import` keyword, something like this:

```
#import "AddStaticContentMissingName.js"
#import "AddStaticContent.js"
```

It's working and both scripts are running but second one starts where first one ends and that is what bothers me. I can set first one to end when the second one needs but I don't like it. I just one to script do what should test and then end. So is it possible to before each test restart application or something like that? I want to have UI testing automate as possible so what or you using? Or are you using another tool then UI Automation?

Bonus question: I was looking for solution how to run this from command line and/or with Xcode Server. I guess Xcode Server is problem but for command line there is a solution. Problem with solution which I found is that I isn't portable right? I don't have any way how can I add some script to my repository and if someone try use it there would be problems with paths. Example of command I found:

```
instruments \
-w your_ios_udid \
-t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" \
name_of_your_app \
-e UIASCRIPT absolute_path_to_the_test_file
```

Comment: You should split the bonus question into its own question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the application between scripts, you need to do it yourself with a combination of app code and UIAutomation code. (Apple will be replacing Instruments with something that works better, but for now this is the only way.)

For example, if your application doesn't use the "shake" gesture for anything, you could use that to trigger a restart within your app (not closing it, just returning it to a known state).  Then at the top of every UIAutomation script, you could just [call the method for the shake gesture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/shake).

In the [testing framework we wrote](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator), we set up our own [RPC channel](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/docs/Bridge.md) to allow us to expose non-UI functionality (like resetting the app) to automation scripts.  It really doesn't matter what system you use to make it happen, as long as you can reliably get the app to a known state.

Comment: Thanks for anwer. I was looking for solution that would need just add a few lines of code to javascript files and that's all. I guess its not possible. Thanks for your "hacks" but I think for my purpose it would be best if each script returns to main page after it do what should test.

Comment: That's a good strategy, but if any of the scripts fail, all the subsequent actions you have scripted will also fail.

Comment: Yea, that's why I was thinking about "reseting" application. Maybe your solution with some gesture could be the right one.

Comment: Since you can run instruments from the command line you should be able to write a script that will kick off each test one at a time in their own instance of instruments. That will restart the app but if you have state restoration you may have to do extra work to get back to the beginning of the app

Answer (score 1):

I might be too late for this but it's totally possible to accomplish what you want. Basically, create a bash script (or any other script) and include the commands to run your two automation scripts:

`#!/bin/bash
instruments -w <UDID> -t <template> <app> -e UIASCRIPT <script1>
instruments -w <UDID> -t <template> <app> -e UIASCRIPT <script2>`

Run that and your app will restart after the first script creating a trace file per run.

Comment: Nope, it's not problem that you post this little late. Looks like it could work. I just few days ago find out that UI Automation is deprecated and with Xcode 7 Apple presents new way how to test UI.

Comment: @LiborZapletal not being deprecated. It still works on Xcode 7 but they've also added a new UI Test that uses XCTest (ObjC and/or Swift).

Comment: According to Apple, UIAutomation will be deprecated a year after XCTest is out of its beta.

Comment: @Ian is that written anywhere? I couldn't find anything about that. Can you please post the link?

Comment: My coworker was at WWDC where they announced this. It's probably in one of their videos.